# How to make list in KIVY out of pandas result

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

I am trying to show the result of my prediction in table/list in kivy but nothing work??! I don't know how to do it. Help me !! Really appreciate the help..

class Recommendation(Screen):

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(Recommendation, self).__init__(**kwargs)
# def do_recommend_me(self):

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='',
        port='',
        database='RRMS'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    articles_df = pd.read_sql_query(''' SELECT Preferences.idUser,Preferences.event_type,Restaurant.rest_ID,\
                                        Restaurant.rest_name,Restaurant.text FROM Preferences JOIN Restaurant\
                                        on Preferences.rest_ID = Restaurant.rest_ID''', mydb)
    # df = pd.DataFrame(articles_df, columns=['rest_ID','idUser','event_type','rest_name','text'])
    # print(df) #Checked!

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    interactions_df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT Restaurant.rest_name,Restaurant.text,Rating.idUser,Rating.event_type,\
                Rating.rest_ID FROM Restaurant JOIN Rating on Restaurant.rest_ID = Rating.rest_ID''',mydb)
    # df = pd.DataFrame(interactions_df,columns = ['rest_ID','rest_name','rest_name','text','idUser','event_type'])
    # print(df) #Checked!
    mydb.commit()

    # # data munging
    event_type_strength = {
        'VIEW': 1.0,
        'LIKE': 2.0,
        'BOOKMARK': 3.0,
        'FOLLOW': 4.0,
        'COMMENT': 5.0,
    }

    interactions_df['eventStrength'] = interactions_df['event_type'].apply(lambda x:event_type_strength[x])
    users_interactions_count_df = interactions_df.groupby(['idUser', 'rest_ID']).size().groupby('idUser').size()
    print('# users: %d' % len(users_interactions_count_df)) # result
    users_with_enough_interactions_df = users_interactions_count_df[users_interactions_count_df >= 3].reset_index()\
        [['idUser']]
    print('# users with at least 5 interactions: %d' % len(users_with_enough_interactions_df)) # result
    print('# of interactions: %d' % len(interactions_df)) # result
    interactions_from_selected_users_df = interactions_df.merge(users_with_enough_interactions_df,
                                                                how='right',
                                                                left_on='idUser',
                                                                right_on='idUser')
    print('# of interactions from users with at least 3 interactions: %d' % len(interactions_from_selected_users_df))

    def smooth_user_preference(x):
        return math.log(1 + x, 2)
    interactions_full_df = interactions_from_selected_users_df \
        .groupby(['idUser', 'rest_ID'])['eventStrength'].sum() \
        .apply(smooth_user_preference).reset_index()
    print('# of unique user/item interactions: %d' % len(interactions_full_df))
    interactions_full_df.head(5)

    #Evaluation of the model
    interactions_train_df, interactions_test_df = train_test_split(interactions_full_df,
                                                                   stratify=interactions_full_df['idUser'],
                                                                   test_size=0.20,
                                                                   random_state=42)

    print('# interactions on Train set: %d' % len(interactions_train_df))
    print('# interactions on Test set: %d' % len(interactions_test_df))

    # Indexing by idUser to speed up the searches during evaluation
    interactions_full_indexed_df = interactions_full_df.set_index('idUser')
    interactions_train_indexed_df = interactions_train_df.set_index('idUser')
    interactions_test_indexed_df = interactions_test_df.set_index('idUser')

    def get_items_interacted(person_id, interactions_df):
        # Get the user's data and merge in the movie information.
        interacted_items = interactions_df.loc[person_id]['rest_ID']
        return set(interacted_items if type(interacted_items) == pd.Series else [interacted_items])

    # Top-N accuracy metrics consts
    EVAL_RANDOM_SAMPLE_NON_INTERACTED_ITEMS = 5

    class ModelEvaluator:

        def get_not_interacted_items_sample(self, person_id, sample_size, seed=32):
            interacted_items = get_items_interacted(person_id, interactions_full_indexed_df)
            all_items = set(articles_df['rest_ID'])
            non_interacted_items = all_items - interacted_items

            random.seed(seed)
            non_interacted_items_sample = random.sample(non_interacted_items, sample_size)
            return set(non_interacted_items_sample)

        def _verify_hit_top_n(self, item_id, recommended_items, topn):
            try:
                index = next(i for i, c in enumerate(recommended_items) if c == item_id)
            except:
                index = -1
            hit = int(index in range(0, topn))
            return hit, index

        def evaluate_model_for_user(self, model, person_id):
            # Getting the items in test set
            interacted_values_testset = interactions_test_indexed_df.loc[person_id]
            if type(interacted_values_testset['rest_ID']) == pd.Series:
                person_interacted_items_testset = set(interacted_values_testset['rest_ID'])
            else:
                person_interacted_items_testset = set([int(interacted_values_testset['rest_ID'])])
            interacted_items_count_testset = len(person_interacted_items_testset)

            # Getting a ranked recommendation list from a model for a given user
            person_recs_df = model.recommend_items(person_id,
                                                   items_to_ignore=get_items_interacted(person_id,
                                                                                        interactions_train_indexed_df),
                                                   topn=10000000000)

            hits_at_5_count = 0
            hits_at_10_count = 0
            # For each item the user has interacted in test set
            for item_id in person_interacted_items_testset:
                # Getting a random sample (100) items the user has not interacted
                # (to represent items that are assumed to be no relevant to the user)
                non_interacted_items_sample = self.get_not_interacted_items_sample(person_id,
                                                                                   sample_size=EVAL_RANDOM_SAMPLE_NON_INTERACTED_ITEMS,
                                                                                   seed=item_id % (2 ** 32))

                # Combining the current interacted item with the 100 random items
                items_to_filter_recs = non_interacted_items_sample.union(set([item_id]))

                # Filtering only recommendations that are either the interacted item or from a random sample of 100 non-interacted items
                valid_recs_df = person_recs_df[person_recs_df['rest_ID'].isin(items_to_filter_recs)]
                valid_recs = valid_recs_df['rest_ID'].values
                # Verifying if the current interacted item is among the Top-N recommended items
                hit_at_5, index_at_5 = self._verify_hit_top_n(item_id, valid_recs, 5)
                hits_at_5_count += hit_at_5
                hit_at_10, index_at_10 = self._verify_hit_top_n(item_id, valid_recs, 10)
                hits_at_10_count += hit_at_10

            # Recall is the rate of the interacted items that are ranked among the Top-N recommended items,
            # when mixed with a set of non-relevant items
            recall_at_5 = hits_at_5_count / float(interacted_items_count_testset)
            recall_at_10 = hits_at_10_count / float(interacted_items_count_testset)

            person_metrics = {'hits@5_count': hits_at_5_count,
                              'hits@10_count': hits_at_10_count,
                              'interacted_count': interacted_items_count_testset,
                              'recall@5': recall_at_5,
                              'recall@10': recall_at_10}
            return person_metrics

        def evaluate_model(self, model):
            # print('Running evaluation for users')
            people_metrics = []
            for idx, person_id in enumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values)):
                # if idx % 100 == 0 and idx > 0:
                #    print('%d users processed' % idx)
                person_metrics = self.evaluate_model_for_user(model, person_id)
                person_metrics['_person_id'] = person_id
                people_metrics.append(person_metrics)
            print('%d users processed' % idx)

            detailed_results_df = pd.DataFrame(people_metrics) \
                .sort_values('interacted_count', ascending=False)

            global_recall_at_5 = detailed_results_df['hits@5_count'].sum() / float(
                detailed_results_df['interacted_count'].sum())
            global_recall_at_10 = detailed_results_df['hits@10_count'].sum() / float(
                detailed_results_df['interacted_count'].sum())

            global_metrics = {'modelName': model.get_model_name(),
                              'recall@5': global_recall_at_5,
                              'recall@10': global_recall_at_10}
            return global_metrics, detailed_results_df

    model_evaluator = ModelEvaluator()

    #Content Based Filtering Model To recommend the user based on the attributes that users likes


    # try:
    #     _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    # except AttributeError:
    #     pass
    # else:
    #     ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
    #
    # nltk.download()

    # Ignoring stopwords (words with no semantics) from English and Malay (as we have a corpus with mixed languages)
    stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english') + stopwords.words('malay')

    # Trains a model whose vectors size is 5000, composed by the main unigrams and bigrams found in the corpus, ignoring stopwords
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                                 ngram_range=(1, 2),
                                 min_df=0.003,
                                 max_df=0.5,
                                 max_features=5000,
                                 stop_words=stopwords_list)

    item_ids = articles_df['rest_ID'].tolist()
    tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(
        articles_df['rest_name'].apply(lambda x: np.str_(x)) + "" + articles_df['text'].apply(lambda x: np.str_(x)))
    tfidf_feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    tfidf_matrix

    def get_item_profile(item_id):
        idx = item_ids.index(item_id)
        item_profile = tfidf_matrix[idx:idx + 1]
        return item_profile

    def get_item_profiles(ids):
        item_profiles_list = [get_item_profile(x) for x in ids]
        item_profiles = scipy.sparse.vstack(item_profiles_list)
        return item_profiles

    def build_users_profile(person_id, interactions_indexed_df):
        interactions_person_df = interactions_indexed_df.loc[person_id]
        user_item_profiles = get_item_profiles(interactions_person_df['rest_ID'])

        user_item_strengths = np.array(interactions_person_df['eventStrength']).reshape(-1, 1)
        # Weighted average of item profiles by the interactions strength
        user_item_strengths_weighted_avg = np.sum(user_item_profiles.multiply(user_item_strengths),
                                                  axis=0) / np.sum(user_item_strengths)
        user_profile_norm = sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(user_item_strengths_weighted_avg)
        return user_profile_norm

    def build_users_profiles():
        interactions_indexed_df = interactions_train_df[interactions_train_df['rest_ID'] \
            .isin(articles_df['rest_ID'])].set_index('idUser')
        user_profiles = {}
        for person_id in interactions_indexed_df.index.unique():
            user_profiles[person_id] = build_users_profile(person_id, interactions_indexed_df)
        return user_profiles

    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    # with warnings.catch_warnings():
    #     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

    user_profiles = build_users_profiles()
    len(user_profiles)

    #21 ganti dengan self.ids.kenal.text
    myprofile = user_profiles[21]
    print(myprofile.shape)
    pd.DataFrame(sorted(zip(tfidf_feature_names,
                            user_profiles[21].flatten().tolist()), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:6],
                 columns=['token', 'relevance'])

    class ContentBasedRecommender:

        MODEL_NAME = 'Content-Based'

        def __init__(self, items_df=None):
            self.item_ids = item_ids
            self.items_df = items_df

        def get_model_name(self):
            return self.MODEL_NAME

        def _get_similar_items_to_user_profile(self, person_id, topn=1000):
            # Computes the cosine similarity between the user profile and all item profiles
            cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(user_profiles[person_id], tfidf_matrix)
            # Gets the top similar items
            similar_indices = cosine_similarities.argsort().flatten()[-topn:]
            # Sort the similar items by similarity
            similar_items = sorted([(item_ids[i], cosine_similarities[0, i]) for i in similar_indices],
                                   key=lambda x: -x[1])
            return similar_items

        def recommend_items(self, user_id, items_to_ignore=[], topn=10, verbose=False):
            similar_items = self._get_similar_items_to_user_profile(user_id)
            # Ignores items the user has already interacted
            similar_items_filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in items_to_ignore, similar_items))

            recommendations_df = pd.DataFrame(similar_items_filtered, columns=['rest_ID', 'recStrength']) \
                .head(topn)

            if verbose:
                if self.items_df is None:
                    raise Exception('"items_df" is required in verbose mode')

                recommendations_df = recommendations_df.merge(self.items_df, how='left',
                                                              left_on='rest_ID',
                                                              right_on='rest_ID')[
                   # ['recStrength', 'rest_ID', 'rest_name', 'Rating']]
                    ['recStrength', 'rest_ID', 'rest_name']]


            return recommendations_df

    content_based_recommender_model = ContentBasedRecommender(articles_df)

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

    # print('Evaluating Content-Based Filtering model...')
    cb_global_metrics, cb_detailed_results_df = model_evaluator.evaluate_model(content_based_recommender_model)
    print('\nGlobal metrics:\n%s' % cb_global_metrics)
    cb_detailed_results_df.head(5)

    # Creating a sparse pivot table with users in rows and items in columns
    users_items_pivot_matrix_df = interactions_train_df.pivot(index='idUser',
                                                              columns='rest_ID',
                                                              values='eventStrength').fillna(0)
    users_items_pivot_matrix_df.head(10)
    users_items_pivot_matrix = users_items_pivot_matrix_df.values
    users_items_pivot_matrix[:3]
    users_ids = list(users_items_pivot_matrix_df.index)
    users_ids[:10]
    users_items_pivot_sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(users_items_pivot_matrix)
    users_items_pivot_sparse_matrix

    # The number of factors to factor the user-item matrix. 5 are being reduces because of the
    # of the dataset
    NUMBER_OF_FACTORS_MF = 5
    # Performs matrix factorization of the original user item matrix
    # U, sigma, Vt = svds(users_items_pivot_matrix, k = NUMBER_OF_FACTORS_MF)
    U, sigma, Vt = svds(users_items_pivot_sparse_matrix, k=NUMBER_OF_FACTORS_MF)

    U.shape
    U.shape
    sigma = np.diag(sigma)
    sigma.shape
    all_user_predicted_ratings = np.dot(np.dot(U, sigma), Vt)
    all_user_predicted_ratings

    all_user_predicted_ratings_norm = (all_user_predicted_ratings - all_user_predicted_ratings.min()) / (
                all_user_predicted_ratings.max() - all_user_predicted_ratings.min())

    # Converting the reconstructed matrix back to a Pandas dataframe
    cf_preds_df = pd.DataFrame(all_user_predicted_ratings_norm, columns=users_items_pivot_matrix_df.columns,
                               index=users_ids).transpose()
    cf_preds_df.head(5)
    len(cf_preds_df.columns)

    class CFRecommender:

        MODEL_NAME = 'Collaborative Filtering'

        def __init__(self, cf_predictions_df, items_df=None):
            self.cf_predictions_df = cf_predictions_df
            self.items_df = items_df

        def get_model_name(self):
            return self.MODEL_NAME

        def recommend_items(self, user_id, items_to_ignore=[], topn=10, verbose=False):
            # Get and sort the user's predictions
            sorted_user_predictions = self.cf_predictions_df[user_id].sort_values(ascending=False) \
                .reset_index().rename(columns={user_id: 'recStrength'})

            # Recommend the highest predicted rating movies that the user hasn't seen yet.
            recommendations_df = sorted_user_predictions[~sorted_user_predictions['rest_ID'].isin(items_to_ignore)] \
                .sort_values('recStrength', ascending=False) \
                .head(topn)

            if verbose:
                if self.items_df is None:
                    raise Exception('"items_df" is required in verbose mode')

                recommendations_df = recommendations_df.merge(self.items_df, how='left',
                                                              left_on='rest_ID',
                                                              right_on='rest_ID')[
                    ['recStrength', 'rest_ID', 'rest_name']] #Rating

            return recommendations_df

    cf_recommender_model = CFRecommender(cf_preds_df, articles_df)
    print('Evaluating Collaborative Filtering (SVD Matrix Factorization) model...')
    cf_global_metrics, cf_detailed_results_df = model_evaluator.evaluate_model(cf_recommender_model)
    print('\nGlobal metrics:\n%s' % cf_global_metrics)
    cf_detailed_results_df.head(5)

    class HybridRecommender:

        MODEL_NAME = 'Hybrid'

        def __init__(self, cb_rec_model, cf_rec_model, items_df, cb_ensemble_weight=1.0, cf_ensemble_weight=1.0):
            self.cb_rec_model = cb_rec_model
            self.cf_rec_model = cf_rec_model
            self.cb_ensemble_weight = cb_ensemble_weight
            self.cf_ensemble_weight = cf_ensemble_weight
            self.items_df = items_df

        def get_model_name(self):
            return self.MODEL_NAME

        def recommend_items(self, user_id, items_to_ignore=[], topn=10, verbose=False):
            # Getting the top-1000 Content-based filtering recommendations
            cb_recs_df = self.cb_rec_model.recommend_items(user_id, items_to_ignore=items_to_ignore,
                                                           verbose=verbose,
                                                           topn=1000).rename(
                columns={'recStrength': 'recStrengthCB'})

            # Getting the top-1000 Collaborative filtering recommendations
            cf_recs_df = self.cf_rec_model.recommend_items(user_id, items_to_ignore=items_to_ignore,
                                                           verbose=verbose,
                                                           topn=1000).rename(
                columns={'recStrength': 'recStrengthCF'})

            # Combining the results by contentId
            recs_df = cb_recs_df.merge(cf_recs_df,
                                       how='outer',
                                       left_on='rest_ID',
                                       right_on='rest_ID').fillna(0.0)

            # Computing a hybrid recommendation score based on CF and CB scores
            # recs_df['recStrengthHybrid'] = recs_df['recStrengthCB'] * recs_df['recStrengthCF']
            recs_df['recStrengthHybrid'] = (recs_df['recStrengthCB'] * self.cb_ensemble_weight) \
                                           + (recs_df['recStrengthCF'] * self.cf_ensemble_weight)

            # Sorting recommendations by hybrid score
            recommendations_df = recs_df.sort_values('recStrengthHybrid', ascending=False).head(topn)

            if verbose:
                if self.items_df is None:
                    raise Exception('"items_df" is required in verbose mode')

                recommendations_df = recommendations_df.merge(self.items_df, how='left',
                                                              left_on='rest_ID',
                                                              right_on='rest_ID')[
                    ['recStrengthHybrid', 'rest_ID', 'rest_name']]

            return recommendations_df

    hybrid_recommender_model = HybridRecommender(content_based_recommender_model, cf_recommender_model, articles_df,
                                                 cb_ensemble_weight=1.0, cf_ensemble_weight=100.0)

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

    print('Evaluating Hybrid model...')
    hybrid_global_metrics, hybrid_detailed_results_df = model_evaluator.evaluate_model(hybrid_recommender_model)
    print('\nGlobal metrics:\n%s' % hybrid_global_metrics)
    hybrid_detailed_results_df.head(5)

    global_metrics_df = pd.DataFrame([cb_global_metrics, cf_global_metrics, hybrid_global_metrics]) \
        .set_index('modelName')
    global_metrics_df

    def inspect_interactions(person_id, test_set=True):
        if test_set:
            interactions_df = interactions_test_indexed_df
        else:
            interactions_df = interactions_train_indexed_df
        return interactions_df.loc[person_id].merge(articles_df, how='left',
                                                    left_on='rest_ID',
                                                    right_on='rest_ID') \
            .sort_values('eventStrength', ascending=False)[['eventStrength',
                                                            'rest_ID',
                                                            'rest_name']] #rating
    # 21 is self.ids.kenal.text
    inspect_interactions(21, test_set=False).head(5)
    print(hybrid_recommender_model.recommend_items(21, topn=2, verbose=True)) ------> want to show this to kivy screen
```

This is the result of the print above, but it only print in command prompt

[This picture shown how the result look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYv5P.png)

Comment: You say it doesn't work.. so what's the expected output and what do you get instead? Any chance of making a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: The expected outcome: I want the result on the command prompt to be shown on my Recommendation Screen. I had use list but, it turn out to be error. I don't know the right way to show the result on the screen @creanion

Comment: I just don't know how to make the result print(hybrid_recommender_model.recommend_items(21, topn=2, verbose=True)) to screen