# Pandas to kivy MDDataTable/DataframeGUIKivy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kivy

Anyone can help regarding DataframeGUIKivy? I had go through the documentation but I can really understand how does it works .. If anyone can help me.

As I try to display data in kivy screen from the result I got in <class'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

The method I had to try is using MDDataTable but, I had know idea what row should I refer to?

Really appreciate the helps.

[The output on kivy screen should be the same as per result on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvCQW.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72761686/how-to-make-list-in-kivy-out-of-pandas-result?noredirect=1#comment128520331_72761686

Comment: Link above is my code